# Multiclass classification problem: how to analyze data to determine affect on precision?

Tags: feature-selection, svm, precision

I have a multiclass text classification problem being solved by SVM. There are $K$ mutually exclusive classes but my task is to improve precision while maintaining reasonable recall of only $k \ll K$ of them. What are standard analysis techniques to determine what features computed from raw data affect precision the most? This would include techniques for "manual" analysis when one visually inspects a relatively small subset of the data looking for the "right" patterns, and those for large scale data transformation/visualization.